# React Link async/await does not wait code block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Hey I am trying to make small application for React-router I am trying to send API request (I do not have backend thats why im using promises) When i click Link it is redirecting not waiting my async/await could you tell me what am i doing wrong?
First thought i can pass history with props and then

```
history.push("/someURL");
```

But my second thought is if i could do this with <Link I will pass less props (history).

To sum up i need to wait until my request(promise) over after that i need to change url

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #24b571;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const SaveButton = ({
  children,
  saveValidation,
  message,
  to,
  setIsLoading,
}) => {
  const promiseFunc = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(5);
      }, 5000);
    });

  const onClickHandler = async (event) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const control = saveValidation(); // returns true or false
    if (!control) {
      toast.error(message);
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      try {
        const a = await promiseFunc();
        alert(a);
      } catch {
        alert('error');
      }
      console.log(control);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <Link to={to}>
      <StyledButton onClick={onClickHandler}>{children}</StyledButton>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default SaveButton;

SaveButton.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  saveValidation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  message: PropTypes.string,
  setIsLoading: PropTypes.func,
};
SaveButton.defaultProps = {
  message: 'Fill all values',
  setIsLoading: () => {},
};
```

Comment: For tags i could be wrong on javascript/html thats why i added javascript tag

Comment: Browser event handling does not understand `async` event handler functions.

Comment: @Pointy is there anything i can do like event.preventDefault(); and then 
"event.unpreventDefault();"

Comment: No, there is not. When your handler returns, the browser will ignore the return value and consider the event to be completed.

Comment: You could do the things suggested but the onClick needs to be on the Link, not the StyledButton as they are acting independently of one another (the Links redirects while the StyledButton runs the handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The main issue here is that you are rendering ***TWO*** components/elements a user could interact with, which is generally considered anti-pattern in UI/UX.  The button is clicked and *its* `onClick` handler is invoked, and the click event bubbles and the `Link` handles it by navigating. These events are handled separately from one another. You *could* stop the `onClick` event propagation in the button's click handler, but then the `Link` would stop working.

## Solution

I suggest using the styled button alone and at the end of the asynchronous logic issue an imperative navigation instead of the declarative navigation offered by the `Link`. Use the `useHistory` hook from `react-router-dom` (*or `useNavigate` if using RRDv6*).

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; // <-- import hook
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ...
`;

const SaveButton = ({
  children,
  saveValidation,
  message,
  setIsLoading,
  to,
}) => {
  const history = useHistory(); // <-- use hook

  const promiseFunc = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    ...
  });

  const onClickHandler = async (event) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const control = saveValidation();
    if (!control) {
      toast.error(message);
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      try {
        const a = await promiseFunc();
        alert(a);
      } catch {
        alert('error');
      }
      console.log(control);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
    history.push(to); // <-- imperative navigation
  };

  return (
    <StyledButton onClick={onClickHandler}>{children}</StyledButton>
  );
};
```